# How to cross-reference two dictionaries in python. So they can print a nice excel-like table

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

So I currently have dict set like this:

```
Dict = {'customer1': {datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 15, 14, 34, 55): '12', datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 16, 14, 34, 55): '14'}, 'customer2': {datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 16, 14, 34, 55): '16', datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 17, 14, 34, 55): '18'}}
```

What I want to print is this:

```
---------  15/06/2017  16/06/2017  17/06/2017
customer1     12          14          --
customer2                 16          18
```

I've thought about creating another temp. dict. sorting first by date and after that with customer names and cross reference these two lists. I did manage to create another dict. looking like this:

```
tempDict = {datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 15, 14, 34, 55): {'customer1': '12'}, datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 16, 14, 34, 55): {'customer1': '14', 'customer2': '16'}, datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 17, 14, 34, 55): {'customer2': '18'}
```

But I couldn't figure out how to cross-reference these lists. I'm still very new to programming in general. Is there any way doing this more efficently? And how can I progress with this method? I'm currently stuck.

```
def excelLikeTable():
    tempDict = {}
    for x in dict.keys():
        for y, z in dict[x].items():
            emptyDict[y] = {}
            emptyDict[y][x] = z
    print('')
    return
```

Comment: Why not use `pandas` for the formatting?

Comment: How would I use that? As I've said I'm new and I don't know all the methods etc.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: `print(pd.DataFrame(Dict).T.fillna('--'))`

Comment: Thanks for all the answers ppl. I hope you have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing the formatting yourself, there is a Python library called `pandas` who has some tools to do proper formatting of (2d) tables.

You can install `pandas` with:

```
pip install pandas
```

(or another `pip` package manager). Then you can use it like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(Dict).T
```

Now `df` is a *dataframe*. If you `print` it, you get:

```
>>> print(df)
          2017-06-15 14:34:55 2017-06-16 14:34:55 2017-06-17 14:34:55
customer1                  12                  14                 NaN
customer2                 NaN                  16                  18
```

Which is more or less what you want I guess.